# how to get the realy activity name but not Subsetting in Setting

Tags: android, settings, fragment

When check log with hierarchyviewer about Setting menu. I found it display SubSetting whatever I click the button. (for example, when I click the wi-fi, it display subsetting, when i click bt, it display subsetting, too). I check some info from intenet, it because fragment.... but I want to know how to get the realy setting name(like before android 3.0).

Comment: I made a service to get the topActivity name, but can not get the correct setting name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is Settings sub-screens are not implemented using separate Activities, so there is no way to get the 'real' Activity that you are looking for. For nearly all Settings screens, the Activity is simply SubSettings Activity which hosts various Fragments.

More details:
In earlier versions of Android, Settings sub-screens were each implemented with their own Activities. Then beginning around Gingerbread, Android re-architected the Settings app (and PreferenceActivity) to use Fragments instead of actual Activities for Settings sub-screens. This allows them to support a split-pane settings user interface (with settings headers on the left, and settings details on the right). For example in Froyo, wifi settings was implemented as an Activity called WifiSettings, but later implementations use a subclass of Fragment (also called WifiSettings).